# How do I align a print command to the right and not the bottom of another print command?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I created an application that calculates windchill. It does so by looping through the interval startWS(starting windspeed that the user inputs) and 99. ideally, it would look like so:
[Ideal run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRlZg.png). However, when I used the following code:

```
import math
x=' '
print("Big Blue Wind Chill") 
print(x) 
airTemp=float(input("Enter air temperature (F): ")) 
startWS=eval(input("Enter starting wind speed (mph): ")) 
print(x)
print("Temperature = " + str(airTemp) + " degrees F") 
print(x) 
def Main(): 
    print("Wind Speed") 
    i=startWS
    for i in range(startWS,91):
        print(i) 
        i=i+1 
Main()    
def oldForumula():
    print("Old Formula") 
    i=startWS
    for i in range(startWS,91):
            old=round(0.081*(3.71*math.sqrt(i)+5.81-0.25*i)*(airTemp-91.4)+91.4)
            print(old) 
            i=i+1 
oldForumula()
def newForumula():
    print("New Formula") 
    i=startWS
    for i in range(startWS,91):
            new=round(35.74+0.6215*airTemp-35.75*(i**0.16)+0.4275*airTemp*(i**0.16))
            print(new) 
            i=i+1 
newForumula()      
def difference():
    print("Difference") 
    i=startWS
    for i in range(startWS,91):
            diff=round((0.081*(3.71*math.sqrt(i)+5.81-0.25*i)*(airTemp-91.4)+91.4)-(35.74+0.6215*airTemp-35.75*(i**0.16)+0.4275*airTemp*(i**0.16)),1)
            print(diff) 
            i=i+1 
difference()
```

I end up with the loops running a line after each other vertically rather than creating a table by running horizontally from each other. It looks like this when I run it: 
[When I run it part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQBEd.png)
[When I run it part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/czTjH.png)

If you know of a meathod in which I could have the "old formula" text be to the right of "Wind Speed" instead of under it, I'd be greatly appreciative if you'd tell me about it.

Edit: This is what happend once I ran xashru's code:
[xashru's code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QohaX.png)

Comment: As the first step you will have to create a data structure that allows you to get the data for a row and not for a column as it is now.

Comment: oh I see. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You dont have to do `i=i+1` in the for loops. Do you want to take every other windspeed? In that case `range` has a third argument which is `step`. Otherwise the for loops take care of incrementing `i` with 1 every iteration.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list of lists. Populate the list first and then print each entry sequentially.

```
entries = x = [[] for i in range(91-startWS)]
def Main(): 
    i=startWS
    for i in range(startWS,91):
        entries[i-startWS].append(i)
        i=i+1 
Main()    
def oldForumula():
    i=startWS
    for i in range(startWS,91):
            old=round(0.081*(3.71*math.sqrt(i)+5.81-0.25*i)*(airTemp-91.4)+91.4)
            entries[i-startWS].append(old)
            i=i+1 
oldForumula()
def newForumula():
    i=startWS
    for i in range(startWS,91):
            new=round(35.74+0.6215*airTemp-35.75*(i**0.16)+0.4275*airTemp*(i**0.16))
            #print(new) 
            entries[i-startWS].append(new)
            i=i+1 
newForumula()      
def difference():
    i=startWS
    for i in range(startWS,91):
            diff=round((0.081*(3.71*math.sqrt(i)+5.81-0.25*i)*(airTemp-91.4)+91.4)-(35.74+0.6215*airTemp-35.75*(i**0.16)+0.4275*airTemp*(i**0.16)),1)
            #print(diff) 
            entries[i-startWS].append(diff)
            i=i+1 
difference()

print('Wind Speed', 'Old Formula', 'New Formula', 'Difference', sep='\t')
for i in range(len(entries)):
    for j in range(4):
        print(entries[i][j], end='\t\t')
    print()
```

Comment: thanks for your help. However, once I ran your code, the alignment was slightly of. see my new edit

Comment: You can add one extra tab or calculate necessary amount of space after each entry to make them all aligned.

Comment: Oh ok. Can you tell me how I would add extra spacing? I’m not sure how I’d move the tables of numbers.